# do not understand passing in arrays to a function

Tags: php, arrays

So, here is my code and I would like to understand how to get the array out.

```
function testArray($name, $ages){
    $name;
    $ages = array();

    echo $name . $ages[0] . '<br>' . $ages[1];
}

testArray("michael", [29,45]);
```

I would like 'ages' to be an array. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: You are overwriting initial value of `$ages` with an empty array.

Comment: just remove the `$ages` reassignment inside the function, its overwritting what you have fed inside it in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the array as array:

```
<?PHP

function testArray($name, $ages){
    //$name;
    //$ages;

    echo $name . $ages[0] . '<br>' . $ages[1];
}

testArray("michael", array(29,45));


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are doing is that you are rewriting your array. Instead of

```
function testArray($name, $ages){
    $name;
    $ages = array();

    echo $name . $ages[0] . '<br>' . $ages[1];
}

testArray("michael", [29,45]);
```

use

```
function testArray($name, $ages){
    $name;

    echo $name . '<br />' . $ages[0] . '<br />' . $ages[1];
}

testArray("michael", [29,45]);
```

and if you get a parse error, use this:

```
function testArray($name, $ages){
    $name;

    echo $name . '<br />' . $ages[0] . '<br />' . $ages[1];
}

testArray("michael", array(29,45));
```